# After enabling BitLocker on Virtual Machine on Hyper-V, I lost access to shared drives

Tags: virtual-machine, encryption, bitlocker

I used to share my local Y: drive with a Virtual Machine running on Windows, using Windows' Hyper-V Manager. Then, the Y: drive would show up in the Virtual Machine as a local drive.

Once I enabled BitLocker on C:, I lost that drive. And it doesn't come back even if I remove it and add it again via Virtual Machine Connection -> Local Resources -> Local Drives and Resources -> More (where Y: is checked as "to be shared").

And yes, I have enabled "Hyper-V Integration Services" (this used to work just fine until I enabled BitLocker).

And no, the drive hasn't been encrypted locally once I enabled BitLocker on the VM (that would be illegal anyway).

And no, enabling BitLocker on the LOCAL drive doesn't make it show up in the VM as if it were "trusted securely" or something.